# How can I perform multiple $lookup's on a query whose results have similar lookup values?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm performing a query on a large number of documents from a collection whose schema looks like this:

```
let mySchema = mongoose.Schema({
title: {
    type: String
},
user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
},
company: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Company'
},
....
});
```

Many of the documents in the above schema will have similar values for `user` and `company` and I'm trying to find the most efficient way to perform this query. Here is what I have, but I feel like it isn't as performant as it could be:

```
this.model('MyModel')
    .aggregate([
        {$match: match_stuff_here},
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "user",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "user"
        }
        $lookup: {
            from: "companies",
            localField: "company",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "company"
        }
        {$project: {
            _id: 1,
            title: 1,
            "user._id": 1,
            "user.name": 1,
            "company._id": 1,
            "company.name": 1
        }}
    ])
    .exec(function (err, data) {
        ...
    });
```

It seems like maybe I should somehow group all of the common user ids and company ids together, do a lookup on them as a group, then add the results back in to the original `match` results. I'm not sure how to do this, or even if that's the right approach. Any ideas on how to optimize this query? Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have it set up with ObjectId and ref, you can use .populate to make life easier https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

In your case, this should work for you:

```
var results = await Model.find(matchQuery).populate('user').populate('company');
console.log(results);
```

**UPDATE**

Assuming that you want to pull data from two collections - 'user' and 'company' there is no single query that will retrieve all data needed. You will need atleast 3 calls - match query, get user data, get company data. To my understand, it will map what it needs to populate, then query for the data. You can view the function in source https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/4.3.7/lib/model.js#L2456

You can also see the queries mongoose uses during the population by enabling debug

```
mongoose.set('debug', true);
```

This guy explains it pretty well http://frontendcollisionblog.com/mongodb/2016/01/24/mongoose-populate.html

Comment: There are some cases where $lookup is more useful for what we're doing. Also, It's my understanding that both populate and lookup will go through each document returned after the match statement and "populate" each one of them, one at a time. What I'm looking for is a way to get all of the similar user ids and company ids and then "populate" them in one query, then inject the result back in to the original results.

Comment: Updated my answer to address your concern about performance issues with populate and lookup. Depending on how your data is structured, and what you're trying to do, populate or lookup might not be the best path as well.